# paypal IPN listener stopped working

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My ipn listener stopped working today (1/22/16).  I have read the articles and the paypal docs my code follows their docs exactly, as far as I can see.  I am testing in the sandbox now.  The issue is that I am getting an http connection error and that stops everything.  The line is :

```
if (!$fp) {
//can't go on
}
```

Here's the full code

```
<?php

$log = fopen("ipn.log", "a");
fwrite($log, "\n\nipn - " . gmstrftime ("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S", time()) . "\n");

header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); 

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

fwrite($log,"$req is: " . $req."\r\n");

$sandbox=1;

if($sandbox == 1) {
    $header = "POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen("tls://www.sandbox.paypal.com", "443", $errno, $errstr, 30);
} else {

    $header = "POST https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen ("ssl://www.paypal.com", "443", $errno, $errstr, 30);
}


fputs($fp, $header . $req);

fwrite($log,"error no= " . $errno . " errstr= " . $errstr . "\r\n");
// ABOVE RETURNS 0 FOR $errno and null for $errstr


if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR HAPPENS HERE
fwrite($log, "http error\r\n");
} else {

    while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    $res = trim($res);

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // do stuff here
        fwrite($log, "verified\r\n");
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        fwrite($log, "invalid\r\n");
        } 
    }
fclose ($fp);
}
fclose ($log);
?>
```

==================
After running the log file looks like this:

```
ipn - Jan 23 2016 00:06:14
$req is: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Fri+Jan+22+2016+15%3A30%3A44+GMT-0800+%28Pacific+Standard+Time%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=378619000&notify_version=2.1&custom=2_2%2Bxc&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AIlWjbxX7iz7ACchkv5lDNHsBr8a
error no= 0 errstr= 
http error
```

Comment: Your code should log more than just 'http error'. Surely there are error codes available?

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Not sure how to get that error code, but I gave up on this approach after hours of banging my head against the wall and used the cURL approach from this page: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php.  Worked first time.  Newby to stackoverload - is there something I should do to close out this thread?

Comment: Until you solve that your question is unanswerable. It is in principle for other people to know what's happening when the only information provided is an error message of your own devising.

Comment: Not quite unanswerable, as it was by latest post.

Answer (score 0):

Update on this.

I gave up trying to make the above approach work and used the cURL approach from this page: github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php
Worked first time after putting in my particulars.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

"$header = "POST https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";"...

try:

"$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";"....

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on the same day.  After research with PayPal I discovered that PayPal changed their security protocol on Jan 20 2016 in the sandbox.  You need to make sure that your webserver uses TLS 1.2 and HTTP 1.1 protocols.  Contact your Host if your website is hosted and you are not sure.

These are the comments from PayPal that contain details of the Sandbox changes and what you as a developer may need to do:

Sandbox has been updated to the latest TLS protocol. You will need to make these changes in order to integrate properly with Sandbox. Here is a microsite that PayPal has put together to help with updates:
https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913&expand=true&locale=en_US

Here is the first link to the TLS 1.2 and HTTP/ 1.1 Upgrade: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US

I ended up hard coding the security profile that my PayPal IPN Listener page used (I am developing in ASP.NET) like this:

'set the security protocol to use

```
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Now my IPN listener is working again in the PayPal sandbox.